# Handling special characters like greek letters in HTML forms vs. MySQL DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

please help me solve the following problem:

**CONFIGURATION:**

HTML charset: windows-1250

DB charset / collation: cp1250 COLLATE cp1250_czech_cs (I cant use UTF-8 because I need proper CZECH collation, case sensivity, etc.)

**PROBLEM:**

Sometimes I need to store to my database special char like greek letter, or <tag>. How to set up the process of storing values from HTML forms to DB and vice versa + displaying values so that there will be no html entities in DB and in forms or when displaying there will be always the real character (not the entity).

Thanks 4 any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no answer given the requirements because you need some way of escaping the unicode characters, and so you might just as well use html entiites and store them in the DB.

This would work well together with using the php filter functions and FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS on inputs.

If you don't like that, use Unicode in the DB.